# Retrieving the email from cognito

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

How can I retrieve the email from the user object in the cognito client? I've tried with camelCase and Capitalized as well and nothing. I'm trying to supply it to the API Gateway so that I can run auth functions from the front end

```
import {CognitoIdentityProviderClient, paginateListUsers} from '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider';

const cognito = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({});

export const handler = async function (event, context, callback) {

    const paginator = paginateListUsers({client: cognito}, {
        UserPoolId: '<region>',
        AttributesToGet: ["email"],
        Filter: '',
        Limit: 60
    });


    let logins = [];

    for await (const page of paginator) {
        for (const user of page.Users) {
            logins.push(
                {
                    "username": user.Username,
                    "email": user.email
                }
            );
        }
    }

    return logins;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The users email is held withing the attributes parameter, which you should be able to access like this:

```
const emails = response.Users.map(user => {
            const emailAttribute = user.Attributes.find(attr => attr.Name === "email");
            return emailAttribute ? emailAttribute.Value : null;
        });
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html#API_ListUsers_ResponseElements

Comment: Do you mean, mapping the response from my client? In the useEffect call in my case (react). I don't have a response in the Lambda function

Comment: Mapping the response.Users in React comes back undefined because the email is not being pushed into the API that is producing the response to begin with

Comment: Try by setting email on the AttributesToGet parameter: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html#CognitoUserPools-ListUsers-request-AttributesToGet

Comment: I’m already doing that :(